# JSTL method call with parameter

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am new to JSTL and looking for a way to call a method in a 'when' clause using JSTL. 
I import this way:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

And then I call the method using this syntax later in the JSP:

```
<c:when test= "${sessionBean.aBooleanMethod(form.userName)}" >
```

The problem is, I get this error:

```
 ...contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing:  ${sessionBean.aBooleanMethod(form.userName)}
```

Please let me know if I need to include any more information or you have any questions! Thanks and I appreciate any answers/ideas!

Comment: I already tried the solutions in that thread, for example this type of syntax "${bean.getArray(foo)}" doesn't work for me. I am using exactly the same: "${sessionBean.aBooleanMethod(form.userName)}"

Comment: did you check that you are running a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (e.g. Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc) with a web.xml declared conform Servlet 3.0. with EL 2.2 ?

Comment: Ugh yeah, I just realized that now! I have to use Jboss 5.2 so I cannot update to 6... I suppose I need to find a workaround in that case. Cheers for helping out!

Comment: In the same link you can find out alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. In this case, the easiest way to fix was is use a Boolean field in my form instead of using a method call and then test that field in JSTL:

```
<c:when test="${form.someBooleanField}">
```